# Apache Pig how to replace all comma in chararray

Tags: apache-pig, data-cleaning

I'm trying to replace all comma in a chararray like this:

Example of input lines:

`1,compras com cartão, comprei (cp1,cp2,cp3), 206-01-01 00:00:00`

Output example:

`1,compras com cartão, comprei (cp1 cp2 cp3), 206-01-01 00:00:00`

Using this approach:

`raw_data = LOAD 's3://datalake/example'
          USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','NO_MULTILINE') AS (id:int, transaction:chararray, transaction_name:chararray, date:chararray);`

`apply_cleanness = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE id:int, ransaction:chararray, REPLACE(transaction_name,',','') as transaction_name, date:chararray;`

But this command just remove the first occurrence of comma, and the result is:

`1,compras com cartão, comprei (cp1 cp2, cp3), 206-01-01 00:00:00`

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post an entire row of data also? Looks like you are loading the data into 2 fields and replacing the comma in the first field only.

Comment: If you want to validate that it is not 'just replacing the first comma', wrap another replace around it. I would expect @inquisitive_mind to be correct, and in that case the second replace will do nothing.

Comment: But this field is a 'open field' in my database, that means the user can put N commas. And using this approach I will need read the logs frequently just to find this kind of errors.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind I test the suggested approach and i think you are right. I add this line `REPLACE(REPLACE(myChararray,',',''),',','')` and the 'second' comma still there. I'm reading this value from a CSV, so any idea to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CarlosEduardo You have post your data before we can help.Please post few records from your file and the expected output

Comment: @inquisitive_mind I changed the text, if is not enough, just tell me. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlosEduardo See below for my answer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Is there a better alternative to my solution below?

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear demarkation of the 3rd field.You have 2 options.Enclose the 3rd field in quotes and then use the pigscript you have.

```
1,compras com cartão, "comprei (cp1,cp2,cp3)", 206-01-01 00:00:00

raw_data = LOAD 's3://datalake/example' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','NO_MULTILINE') AS (id:int, transaction:chararray, transaction_name:chararray, date:chararray);
apply_cleanness = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE id:int, ransaction:chararray, REPLACE(transaction_name,',','') as transaction_name, date:chararray;
```

Alternatively, you can load the fields using comma as the delimiter and then generate the 3rd field as the combination of 3,4,5 fields in the load.See below

```
A = LOAD 'test16.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 as id:int,$1 as transaction:chararray,CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT($2,' '),$3),' '),$4) as transaction_name:chararray,$5 as date:chararray; 
DUMP B;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @inquisite_mind thank to answer my question. I really like this approach and another solution is change the delimiter. I change to | delimiter, and now it's working. thanks again.